# Definite article used in beginning of a sentence

Tags: german-to-english, grammar-identification

I am going through some German Math notes. The notes begin with this sentence:

> Die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte haben alle vorausgesetzt, dass wir die jeweiligen Grenzwerte schon “besitzen".

Could someone explain in details how the 'die' is used in the beginning?

Comment: So how did you figure out the 'die' is describing the 'regeln' part?

Comment: I've heard of this, but it's not often seen, sort of like Bigfoot. Thanks for providing evidence that it actually exists.

Comment: Who me? For which? @RDBury

Comment: @Buraian: Yes you :) I had heard of the phenomenon of putting an entire clause between an article and a noun in German, something which is not possible in English. This was long before I started studying German seriously. But I've been studying German seriously for a while now and I don't recall ever seeing it "in the wild". Now I know that it really exists.

Comment: @Buraian: PS. I probably heard about it in Mark Twain's "The Awful German Language". His translation of an example: "But when he, upon the street, the (in-satin-and-silk-coverednow-very-unconstrainedly-after-the-newest-fashion-dressed) government counsellor's wife met, ..."

Comment: @RDBury, I can imagine that if it had just said “oben” instead of “im vorangehenden Kapitel” you would have hardly noticed it.

Comment: @Carsten S: That may well be true. Another factor is that I haven't read a lot of academic German (yet).

Comment: Ah yes, I read that too. Twain is awesome. I thought given your experience you'd have seen it all, but I guess we all have more to learn :P

Comment: @RDBury, this construction is not restricted to academic writing.  I just did a Google search for “im letzten Jahr begonnene” and got a lot of results that fit what I expected. In German, if you can put an adjective somewhere, you can also put a past participle, and that can carry other stuff with it.

Comment: @Carsten S: David Vogt's answer mentioned that the construction is most frequent in academic German. I'm sure it occurs elsewhere as well, but most of my practice reading consists of pop song lyrics and video game dialog.

Comment: @Buraian: Not that much experience, I'm just a learner who happens to be overly fascinated with the grammatical aspects of the language. The more you study German, the funnier Twain's essay gets; I just re-read it again. But it was written over 140 years ago and German and changed a bit since then. For instance the dative *-e* ending is mostly gone now, and the meaning of *Weib* is very different now.

Comment: "Wenn er aber auf der Strasse **der** in Sammt und Seide gehüllten jetz sehr ungenirt nach der neusten mode gekleideten **Regierungsrathin** begegnet." (Mark Twain, "[The Awful German Language](https://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/texts/twain.german.html#1)")

Comment: @planetmaker: please stop misusing comments! Comments are not made to answer questions. Please either write proper answers or nothing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One characteristic of German has been called *Klammerstruktur*: the phenomenon that words belonging together can be separated and occur at a vast distance from each other, which often poses problems for language learners.

The phenomenon of *verbal bracketing* is encountered at an early stage for learners.

> Ich **habe unterschrieben**.
>
> Ich **habe** in der vergangenen Woche nach reiflicher Überlegung den Vertrag für die neue Wohnung **unterschrieben**.

*Habe unterschrieben* forms a unit, yet in the second example, the listener has to wait a very long time for the participle *unterschrieben* to arrive. Before the utterance has been completed, the listener has to guess at what activity the utterance is about, or has to defer interpretation until it has been completed. Basically, the entire sentences intervenes between auxiliary and participle.

Your example shows a similar *nominal bracketing*, with the article and accompanying noun forming a unit that is separated by what is basically a sentence, paraphrasable by a relative clause.

> **die** im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten **Regeln**
>
> **die Regeln**, die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelt wurden

The correct strategy for interpreting such phrases is to keep scanning to the right after the article for a combination of adjective and noun that fits.

> die … behandelt**en** Regeln *(weak adjective, plural noun)*
>
> ein im vorangegangenen Kapitel behandelt**er** Ansatz *(strong adjective, masculine noun)*
>
> aus natürlichen Quellen stammend**es** Wasser *(strong adjective, noun that doesn't require an article)*

The phenomenon is so prevalent in academic writing that someone dedicated a chapter of a book to describing an algorithm for decoding such phrases; see [Tips for translating participial constructions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52015/tips-for-translating-participial-constructions). (The book is *The key to German translation* by Cecil Pollard.)

Comment: What is a weak adjective? Do you mean adjective with a weak ending?

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, it would have been more precise to say *adjective with a proper ending*. If the article at the beginning has no ending or there is no article, the adjective would of course have a strong ending: *ein im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelt**es** Thema*, *direkt aus der Natur stammend**es** Wasser*.

Comment: That the verb in such a bracket structure comes only versus the end so that the poor reader has to guess what the sentence is actually saying was one of Mark Twain's main complaints in his funny rant [The Awful German Language](https://faculty.georgetown.edu/jod/texts/twain.german.html).

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at a simplified version of the sentence:

> Die Regeln und Sätze, ...

Here it is easy to see that *Die* is simply the article of *Regeln* and *Sätze*.

Now let's add an adjective (which is a particple, but this is not important at this point):

> Die behandelten Regeln und Sätze, ..

Now let's add a bit more:

> Die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze, ...

*Die* is still the article of *Regeln* and *Sätze*, it is just that the attributive phrase *im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten* separates them.

If the adjective is a participle, it can be accompanied by objects and adverbials. This way one can construct quite large attributive phrases.

An even longer example:

> **Die** den Studenten gestern abend in feierlicher Sitzung überreichte **Urkunde**..

Comment: Was it really neccesary to do it like the way the author did? Could he have paired it with the actual noun and preserved meaning?

Comment: @Buraian: Your comment is unclear; note, that it is attractive, to use the described construct instead of a more wordy subclause. Just moving the noun to the position directly after the article is seriously ungrammatical.

Comment: Could you explain more about why it is ungrammatical? @guidot I don't think I understand 100% what you are saying

Comment: @Buraian: it is unlikely to succeed, when I have to guess, what the point is and what you suggest. I propose, that you clarify the question by editing it.

Comment: In German, the adjective always precedes the noun. If you want to place it after the noun, you have to use a subclause or a subclause-like construction.

Comment: `Die Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte, die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelt wurden, haben alle vorausgesetzt, dass wir die jeweiligen Grenzwerte schon “besitzen"` would be an alternative. For me, as a native German, this would be (slightly) harder to understand than the original sentence.

Answer (score 2):

These are the parts of the sentence:

- **Die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte**
  This whole phrase is the subject of the sentence. It is a nominal group (aka "nominal phrase") and it is in nominative case.
- **haben** ... **vorausgesetzt**
  This is the predicate (as defined in German grammar, which is another definition as in English grammar where is it just called "the verb", but a German predicate can have multiple verbs on different places in the sentence, but the bigger difference is, that objects do belong to the predicate in English grammar, while objects are not considered to be part of the predicate in German)
- **alle**
  This indefinite pronoun is a determiner that semantically also belongs to the subject, but stands here at position 3 of the sentence, which is the alternative place for subjects (if they are not at position 1). You could include it into the nominal group that is the subject, but then if replaces the already existing determiner *die* which is the topic of your question:

  > **Alle** im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte
- **dass wir die jeweiligen Grenzwerte schon “besitzen"**
  This is a subjunctive object clause. The whole clause is here instead of the accusative object that the verb *"voraussetzen"* normally requires.

---

Let's dive deeper into the nominal group that is the subject. Each nominal group has a core (usually a noun, this is where the term *nominal* comes from) and some accompanists which can be determiners and attributes.

The core of the nominal group in your sentence is not a single noun but an enumeration:

> **Regeln und Sätze**

To have enumerations where the textbook requires a noun is always possible

But nominal groups also need a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner). This is very often an article (definite or indefinite)

> **der** Kern, **ein** Kern
> <sup>**the** core, **a** core</sup>

But it can also be a demonstrative pronoun, ...

> **dieser** Kern, **jener** Kern
> <sup>**this** core, **that** core</sup>

... a possessive pronoun, ...

> **mein** Kern, **sein** Kern
> <sup>**my** core, **his** core</sup>

... or other kinds of words (numerals, indefinite pronouns, etc.)

> **drei** Kerne, **einige** Kerne, **wessen** Kern?, ...
> <sup>**three** cores, **some** cores, **who's** core?, ...</sup>

In you sentence it is a definite article:

> **die** Regeln und Sätze
> <sup>**the** rules and clauses</sup>

But the core can also have attributes. Attributes are often adjectives:

> der **rote** Apfel
> <sup>the **red** apple</sup>

but also very often objects that can contain other nominal groups. (Here we have prepositional objects, but also genitive objects are very common.)

> der Apfel **in meiner linken Hand**
> <sup>the apple **in my left hand**</sup>

> die Regeln und Sätze **über Grenzwerte**
> <sup>the rules and clauses **about limit values**</sup>

Rule of thumb: Adjectives are left of the core (between determiner and core), objects that are used as attributes are right of the core. Of course you can have both of them:

> der **rote** Apfel **in meiner linken Hand**
> <sup>the **red** apple **in my left hand**</sup>

Instead of adjectives you also can have participles:

> der **gefärbte** Apfel
> <sup>the **colored** apple</sup>

> die **behandelten** Regeln und Sätze
> <sup>the **treated** rules and clauses = the rules and clauses **treated**</sup>

But adjectives and particles can have their own attributes:

> der **rot** gefärbte Apfel
> <sup>the **red** colored apple</sup>

> die **neulich** behandelten Regeln und Sätze
> <sup>the *recently* treated rules and clauses = the rules and clauses treated *recently*</sup>

In the two examples above the words *rot/red* and *neulich/recently* describe properties of the participles *gefärbt/colored* and *behandelt/treated* which by themselves describe properties of the cores. So they are attributes of attributes.

But attributes of attributes are just attributes and can also be something else but adjectives, for example another prepositional object, consisting of a preposition and a nominal group:

> der **von der Sonne** gefärbte Apfel
> <sup>the by the sun colored apple = the apple colored **by the sun**</sup>

> die **im vorangehenden Kapitel** behandelten Regeln und Sätze
> <sup>the **in the previous chapter** treated rules and clauses = the rules and clauses treated **in the previous chapter**</sup>

(Note, that in German attributes of adjectives and participles are always left of them, even if they are objects.)

And you can put this all together to a very nice and elaborated nominal group:

> der von der Sonne gefärbte Apfel in meiner linken Hand
> <sup>the by the sun colored apple in my left hand = the apple colored by the sun in my left hand</sup>

> die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte
> <sup>the in the previous chapter treated rules and clauses about limit values = the rules and clauses about limit values treated in the previous chapter</sup>

And of course you can use this nice nominal phrase as a subject or object in a sentence:

- as the subject

  > **Der von der Sonne gefärbte Apfel in meiner linken Hand** schmeckt gut.
  > <sup>**The by the sun colored apple in my left hand** tastes well. = **The apple colored by the sun in my left hand** tastes well.</sup>

  > **Die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte** sind kompliziert.
  > <sup>**The in the previous chapter treated rules and clauses about limit values** are complicated. = **The rules and clauses about limit values treated in the previous chapter** are complicated.</sup>
- as an object (here: accusative object)

  > Ich betrachte **den von der Sonne gefärbte Apfel in meiner linken Hand.**
  > I watch **the by the sun colored apple in my left hand.** = I watch **the apple colored by the sun in my left hand.**

  > Wir analysieren **die im vorangehenden Kapitel behandelten Regeln und Sätze über Grenzwerte.**
  > <sup>We analyze **the in the previous chapter treated rules and clauses about limit values.** = We analyze **The rules and clauses about limit values treated in the previous chapter.**</sup>