# Multiple consecutive adjectives?

Tags: compound-adjective

Regarding the following sentence, *Ein von unbeugsamen Galliern bevölkertes Dorf hört nicht auf*, meaning, “A village populated by indomitable Gauls does not quit,” do I read correctly that three adjectives in a row are modifying *Dorf*? So, more literally, “One indomitable-Gauls-populated village…”? This would be a monstrosity in English, but of course that doesn’t mean it wouldn’t work in German.

And what is the role of *von* (of) in this sentence? I could understand if the sentence referred to **one of** (*ein von*) many villages, but that is not the case here. There is just a single village under discussion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one adjective modifying the noun: *bevölkertes*. German allows for adjective phrases, units that are similar to sentences. Compare:

> ein [ *von unbeugsamen Galliern* bevölkert ] -es Dorf
>
> ein Dorf, das [ *von unbeugsamen Galliern* bevölkert ] ist

In both instances, the prepositional phrase headed by *von* modifies *bevölkern*, specifying the agent. For practice, it is fun to start with adjectives and build more and more complex phrases.

> ein [ Augenzeugen zufolge seit einigen Jahren von unbeugsamen Gallien bevölkert ] -es Dorf

> ein [ arbeitend ] -der Zeichner
> [ an einem Comic arbeiten ]
> [ heimlich an einem Comic arbeiten ]
> [ schon lange heimlich an einem Comic arbeiten ]
> [ entgegen den Wünschen seiner Frau schon lange heimlich an einem Comic arbeiten ]

> ein Zeichner, der entgegen den Wünschen seiner Frau schon lange heimlich an einem Comic arbeitet

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so surprising, I want to make doubly sure that I understand correctly. Are you saying that the *ein* that begins this sentence and the *Dorf* that comes near the end are actually paired, as in *ein Dorf*? And the adjective phrase (as you now kindly clarify) *von unbeugsamen Galliern bevölkertes* is inserted between *ein* and *Dorf*?

Comment: Yes on both counts. See also https://german.stackexchange.com/a/70240/35111.

Comment: It's paranthetic phrasing and very common in German.

Comment: Very, very useful. Thanks again to both!