# Adjectives skipping declensions...?

Tags: adjective, grammar-identification

> Da der reibungslose Transport von Waren und Versorgungsgütern in Deutschland nach wie vor **auf einwandfrei** funktionierende Straßen angewiesen ist, müssen Bundesstrassen, Autobahnen und Brücken stets repariert und für den Schwerverkehr befahrbar sein.

In the above, why is "einwandfrei" not declined? I think it should be since it is an adjective.

The issue feels reminiscent of the issue discussed in [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/adjectives-meaning-being-determined-by-other-parts-of-sentece) but I am not sure how to map the ideas in the answers of that post to the one here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reading the question title, I thought, well, probably because it’s an adverb. And indeed, “einwandfrei” describes “funktionierend”, not “Straßen”. Adjectives used as adverbs are not declined, indeed that’s how you can often recognise them.