# so vs. sie confusion when doing Lückentexte

Tags: grammar-identification, personal-pronoun

> Die soziale Schnittstelle im Internet wird für viele Menschen zum einzigen Begegnungspunkt mit anderen Menschen, da sie erfolgreich eine Illusion der Intimität und Gemeinsamkeit schafft. **S(o)** entsteht eine Gesellschaft, die es mehr und mehr verlernt, miteinander umzugehen, wenn man sich im echten Leben gegenübersteht.
>
> Ex.18, Mut zur Lücke

> Pflanzliche Gerbstoffe, sogenannte Tannine, verleihen Rotweinen unter anderem ihren herben, trockenen Geschmack. **S(ie)** werden Weinen während der Reifung entweder künstlich zugesetzt oder gelangen über die Holzfässer, in denen der Wein gelagert wird, in den Alkohol.
>
> Ex.22, Mut zur Lücke

Similar context [to this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74889/distinguishing-between-adjective-and-adverb-for-word-inserted-between-article-an). I was tasked with filling the text in the bracket. For the first one, I wrote "ie" instead of "o" and in the second one as "o" instead of "ie". I have noticed that I get confused a lot when the cue is an "S" at the start.

Could someone help me figure out a way to methodically resolve the confusion and figure out which one is more appropriate to use when such a cue is given?

Comment: Meaning? Grammar? Neither "sie entsteht eine Gesellschaft" nor "so werden Weinen zugesetzt" works in either regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's check potential meanings

So

- (This | That) way
- As a consequence
- Sometimes used for questions like "So?" meaning "Is that so?"

Sie

- They (3rd pers. pl)
- You (2nd pers. sg, formal)
- You (2nd pers. pl, formal)

In your case, I think this is solvable by understanding the preceeding sentences.

> Die soziale Schnittstelle im Internet wird für viele Menschen zum einzigen Begegnungspunkt mit anderen Menschen, da sie erfolgreich eine Illusion der Intimität und Gemeinsamkeit schafft. S(o) entsteht eine Gesellschaft, die es mehr und mehr verlernt, miteinander umzugehen, wenn man sich im echten Leben gegenübersteht.

In the first example, the first sentence provides the description of a mechanism (simply put). The following sentence describes a consequence of that mechanism being applied. So meaning "That way". There is no meaning of Sie that would make any sense.

> Pflanzliche Gerbstoffe, sogenannte Tannine, verleihen Rotweinen unter anderem ihren herben, trockenen Geschmack. S(ie) werden Weinen während der Reifung entweder künstlich zugesetzt oder gelangen über die Holzfässer, in denen der Wein gelagert wird, in den Alkohol.

In the second example, the first sentence describes a list of specific chemicals. The second sentence references the list (3rd pers. pl). There is no way "So" (causal or consecutive) would make sense here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So Sie if referenced before. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

Let's analyse:

> S… entsteht eine Gesellschaft, …

The verb *entstehen* does not allow an accusative object. It's *die Gesellschaft*, so *eine Gesellschaft* is either nominative or accusative singular. But it can't be accusative. It's nominative. This is the subject.

*Sie* can also be either nominative or accusative. But the verb *entstehen* does not allow an accusative object and the subject is already taken.

This rules out *sie* completely. The remaining option is ***so***.

---

> S… werden Weinen während der Reifung entweder künstlich zugesetzt oder …

This clause has no item in nominative case at hand. It's missing a subject.

But okay, it's passive voice so we don't strictly need a subject. Or do we? Yes, we do. That is because the verb *zusetzen* requires an accusative object in active voice. So it also requires a subject in passive voice.

This rules out *so* because we had no subject then. The remaining option is ***sie***.

For the second example, you actually have another chance to guess correctly because the sentence has two alternative endings given as *entweder … oder*. The alternative is

> S… gelangen über die Holzfässer, in denen der Wein gelagert wird, in den Alkohol.

This is even easier because it is an active voice clause and it would be also missing a subject if it would not start with *sie*.