# Interpretation of insertions between adjectives and article of a noun

Tags: grammar-identification

> Mit seiner Fülle von Informationen und Attraktionen ist ein Freilichtmuseum ein für alle Altersklassen geeigneter Tagesausflug mit pädagogischem Hintergedanken für die ganze Familie, der sich zum Beispiel in den Schulferien anbietet.

Using the ideas in this  [post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74886/adjectives-skipping-declensions?noredirect=1&lq=1), I got the answer that "für alle Altersklassen" is an adverb, and [in another](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/74781/51342), that it is actually an "attribute" of the adjective "geeigneter".

Are both correct? if so, how do they relate to each other exactly?

Comment: "für alle Altersklassen" appears nowhere in the first linked question or the answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct points of view, but it should be noted that *adverbial* instead of *adverb* is the right word. *Adverb* is a word class/part of speech, while *adverbial* is a syntactical function. So "für alle Altersklassen" is either an adverbial in the *participle clause* of "geeigneter" or an attribute of the *adjective* "geeigneter".

The reason you have these two points of view lies in the nature of participles, which are like a mix of adjectives and verbs. They describe nouns like adjectives, but can have objects like verbs. So you can see "geeigneter" either as something more verb-like, and "für alle Altersklassen" as an adverbial, or as something more adjective-like, and "für alle Altersklassen" as an attribute. It changes nothing in the meaning and the dependency structure, it's just a different way to describe the same thing.

It is also not true that adjectives don't have such attributes, e.g. one could say

> Eine für alle Altersgruppen erfreuliche Nachricht.

And "erfreulich" is not a participle.